# apache2: where is the default virtual host config?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I am install `apache2` on Ubuntu 18.04 using following command:

```bsh
apt install apache2
```

Then I am edit the file `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` to listen port 8090:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 8090

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Then disable all available virtual host:

```
a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

And finally I restarted Apache2.

But I still can access **Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page** via `http://SERVER-IP:8090`:
[image]

So my question is, where is the default virtual host config?

`apache2.conf`  is [here](https://sysadmindata.com/ubuntu-apache2-conf-default/).

Comment: I have restart apache2 after removing the default site.

Comment: That is expected behaviour. You "disabled the default site", which will be always the default vhost that starts with the lower ASCII character, once you create vhosts files. However, you did not disable access by IP address. They are two different things. There are at least 3 ways of forbidding access by IP address.